# Optimizing quadratic form with respect to inner positive definite matrix with a trace constraint

Tags: optimization, matrix-calculus, lagrange-multiplier, matrix-decomposition

Let $\{z_i\}_{i=1}^n$ and $\{w_i\}_{i=1}^n$ be two collections of vectors in $\mathbb R^p$. Let $A$ be a real positive definite $p\times p$ matrix, with Cholesky factorization $LL^T$, where $L$ is also $p\times p$.

I want to solve the following optimization:

$$\min_L  F(L) \rightarrow \min_L \sum_{i=1}^p z^T_i LL^T z_i - w^T_i LL^T w_i$$
subject to the constraint
$$\text{tr}(LL^T) = 1.$$

My approach: Lagrange multipliers. I thought that $\frac{d}{dL} \left(zLL^Tz - wLL^Tw\right) = 2(zz^T-ww^T)L$, and $\frac{d}{dL}\text{Tr}(LL^T) = 2L$, but this doesn't seem to lead to a solution.

**Edited: Rewrote problem to include a positive semi-definite constraint, via the Cholesky factorization.**

Comment: Your constraint does not deal with the off-diagonal elements of $A$. Therefore I can make those elements as large as I wish and make their signs negative, which will drive the function value towards $-\infty$

Comment: Great point. I want to add a positive negative constraint. Will rephrase.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Rather than solve for the Cholesky factor directly, find a solution in terms of a less *structured* matrix, $M$. Let a colon denote the matrix inner product, i.e.
$$\eqalign{
A:B &= {\rm Tr}(AB^T) \cr
M:M &= {\rm Tr}(MM^T) &= \frac{1}{\mu^2} \cr
}$$
Also, for typing convenience let 
$$\eqalign{
 A &= \frac{MM^T}{M:M},\quad\;
 Y &= Y^T = \sum_kz_kz_k^T - w_kw_k^T \cr
}$$
Calculate the gradient of $F$.
$$\eqalign{
 F &= Y:A \cr
dF &= Y:dA \cr 
  &= Y:\Bigg(\frac{dM\,M^T+M\,dM^T}{M:M} - \frac{MM^T\big(dM:M+M:dM\big)}{(M:M)^2}\Bigg) \cr
 &= 2\mu^2\Big(YM-FM\Big):dM \cr
\frac{\partial F}{\partial M}
 &= 2\mu^2\big(YM-FM\big) \cr
}$$
Set the gradient to zero and solve for $M$.
$$\eqalign{
 &YM = F M \cr
}$$
Thus it appears that the columns of $M$ are equal to 
the eigenvector $\{v_k\}$ of $Y$ associated with its minimum eigenvalue $\{\lambda_k\}$, i.e.
$$k = \arg\min_j \lambda_j,\quad F = \lambda_k,\quad 
M = (\,v_k\;v_k\;v_k\;\ldots\,) \,=\, v_k{\large\tt 1}^T
$$

Given the solution in terms of $M$, recover a solution in terms of $L$.
$$\eqalign{
L &= {\rm cholesky}\bigg(\frac{MM^T}{M:M}\bigg) \cr
A &= LL^T = \frac{MM^T}{M:M},\quad\quad 
{\rm Tr}(LL^T) = \frac{M:M}{M:M} = 1 \cr
}$$

Comment: I mostly followed this (have to brush up on some basics with matrix calculus), but I don't quite understand how you conclude $YM=FM$ implies that $M=v_k1^T$. Can you briefly explain this? Also, do you have a good reference for matrix calculus that you would recommend, evidently I'm not strong enough and some of the standard stuff out there, such as Matrix Cookbook, is pretty unreadable for the basics.

Comment: I understand that the columns of M should correspond to eigenvectors of $Y$, but I don't understand why it consists of copies of the eigenvector corresponding to the smallest eigenvalue.

Comment: Because $Y$ operates on $M$ column by column, and must produce the _same value_ of $F$ for every column. Now it is _possible_ that the minimum eigenvalue has multiplicity greater than one. In that case, you could use all of the associated eigenvectors (or linear combinations thereof) as the columns of $M$.

Answer (score 2):

Define the $p\times n$ matrices $Z=[z_1,\dots,z_n]$ and $W=[w_1,\dots,w_n]$ (such that given vectors are respectively their columns). Convince yourself that you can rewrite your optimization problem as
\begin{align}
\min_{A} &<A,ZZ^T-WW^T> \\ &A\geq 0 ~,~<A,I> = 1
\end{align}
where $A\geq 0$ implies $A$ should be positive-semi-definite. Also, for any two symmetric matrices $A,B$, we define $<A,B> = \mathrm{trace}(AB)$. We can define the eigen-decomposition
\begin{align}
A = \sum_{i=1}^{p}\lambda_iu_iu_i^T 
\end{align}
where $u_i$ are the eigen vectors and $\lambda_i$ are the eigen values (of unit-norm). Let $B=ZZ^T-WW^T$. Convince yourselves that your optimization problem of finding $A$ is same as finding pairs $(\lambda_i,u_i)$ in the optimization problem
\begin{align}
\min_{\lambda_i,u_i}&\sum_{i=1}^{p}\lambda_iu_i^TBu_i
\\& \lambda_i\geq 0~,~\forall i
\\& \sum_{i=1}^{p}\lambda_i = 1
\end{align}
From rayleigh-ritz ratio, it follows that for any unit-norm $u_i$, we have that
\begin{align}
u_i^TBu_i\geq \lambda_{min}(B)
\end{align}
and equality is achieved when $u_i$ is the eigen-vector corresponding to $\lambda_{min}(B)$. Thus, it follows that 
\begin{align}A = uu^T
\end{align} where $u$ is the eigen-vector corresponding to smallest eigenvalue of $B$.